# AndroidUnit testing Room in dagger2

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-room, dagger-2

I have created dagger2 module for room database like below:

```
@Module
public class RoomModule {

    @AppScope
    @Provides
    StateDataBase dbEngineerProvider(Context context){
        return Room.databaseBuilder(context, StateDataBase.class, "State.db").build();
    }

    @AppScope
    @Provides
    UserDao getUserDao(StateDataBase db) {
        return db.getUserDao();
    }
}
```

and i initialized dagger in my application class :

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Timber.plant(new Timber.DebugTree());

        component = DaggerAppComponent.builder()
                .networkModule(new NetworkModule(this))
                .build();
    }

    public AppComponent getAppComponent() {
        return component;
    }
}
```

I want to know how possible to make a real test not mock test from my room database in dagger ?

I want to insert a data into my database and in my app i use this data!!!
For example in test i insert username and password of my user and then When i run application i use this data for login to application!! Is it possible?

Comment: For database operation you can not do isolation testing, you need to do integration testing.

Comment: Ok dude i have to use integration testing (Medium test).Do you have sample or reference to how can i use   integration testing room with dagger? I can not find and example @PallaviTapkir

Answer (score 0):

```
@Test
    fun testRoomDatabase() {
        val dao = Room.databaseBuilder(context!!, Database::class.java, "Database.db").build().dao()

        val alertList = ArrayList<Alert>()

        val alert = Alert()
        alert.alertId = 22603
        alert.alertType = 3
        alert.geoFence = ""

        val alert1 = Alert()
        alert1.alertId = 12603
        alert1.alertType = 10
        alert1.geoFence = ""

        alertList.add(alert)
        alertList.add(alert1)

        Assert.assertNotNull(alertList)
        val ids = dao.insertSelectedAlertsToDatabase(alertList)
        Assert.assertEquals(2, ids.size)
        Assert.assertFalse(1 == ids.size)

        // fetch all alerts from database
        val alerts = dao.fetchAllAlerts()/*.test().onComplete()*/
        Assert.assertNotNull(alerts)
    }
```

I Hope you have database in place.

Comment: That's mean i do not need to use dagger in test?@PallaviTapkir